# The same value gets appended in rest post method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rest

I have two models that are related in one-to-one relation. I am defying the save method of one of those models in-service class. But when I saving them through rest API it is appending the same object continously.

I have 2 models Invoice and CustomerOrder with one-to-one relation.

Invoice model

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private LocalDate date;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerOrder")
    private Invoice invoice;

    public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return invoice;
    }

    public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }

    ....
```

and Invoice

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(precision = 8, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    private LocalDate issued;

    private LocalDate due;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;

    public CustomerOrder getCustomerOrder() {
        return customerOrder;
    }

    public void setCustomerOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder) {
        this.customerOrder = customerOrder;
    }
...
```

And my service save method

```
    public void saveInvoice(Invoice invoice, Long order_id) {
        CustomerOrder customerOrder = customerOrderRepository.getById(order_id);
        invoice.setCustomerOrder(customerOrder);
        invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
    }
```

Controller method

```
@PostMapping(path = "{order_id}")
    public void saveInvoice(@RequestBody Invoice invoice,@PathVariable(value = "order_id") Long order_id) {
        invoiceService.saveInvoice(invoice, order_id);
    }
```

But when saving the same object is appending continously.

```
        "id": 3,
        "amount": 10.20,
        "issued": "2020-09-20",
        "due": "2020-09-21",
        "customerOrder": {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2020-09-20",
            "invoice": {
                "id": 3,
                "amount": 10.20,
                "issued": "2020-09-20",
                "due": "2020-09-21",
                "customerOrder": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "date": "2020-09-20",
                    "invoice": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "amount": 10.20,
                        "issued": "2020-09-20",
                        "due": "2020-09-21",
                        "customerOrder": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "date": "2020-09-20",
                            "invoice": { ....
```

On and on.

Comment: It isn't saving it multiple times, but your relation is a bi-directional one and you haven't told Jackson that it is. So it will serialize all fields of Invoice, which has a CustomOrder, which has an Invoice, which has a CustomOrder, which... (well you probably get it by now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is happening actually here:

- `CustomerOrder` Entity has a property of `Invoice` named `invoice`.
- `Invoice` Entity has a property of `CustomerOrder` named `customerOrder`.

While jackson serializer try to serialize this `CustomerOrder` it sees it has a `invoice` property which also has `customerOrder` inside it. Although there is only two object of `customerOrder` & `invoice` referring each other, but while serializing it recursively goes down.

#### Solution:

###### Using `@JsonIgnore`:

Put a `@JsonIgnore` on `cusotmerOrder` property of `Invoice` entity which will prevent serializing `customerOrder` inside the `Invoice` entity.

- Pros: Less overhead
- Cons: Cannot dynamically control when to serialize upto which level.

Using `@JsonIgnore` or using a pair of `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference` has the similar cons.

###### Others:

For dynamically control the depth of your response in different responses (for different routes) you can go for `@JsonView` or `@JsonFilter`.

Usage Examples:

- [How to use @JsonBackReference & @JsonManagedReference](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)
- [How to use @JsonView](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)
- [How to use @JsonFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

@OneToOne Is not best option for the relation, f.e. it limits LAZY loading off entity. Also u have CascadeType.ALL from both sides of the relation which may cause some problems. Change the relation to @OneToMany **one** CustomerOrder and **many** Invoice and drop the cascade. Save CustomerOrder first and then Invoice. But if u want to use @OneToOne check out annotation @MapsId
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

It is not good practice to use directly entity as a **RequestBody** in REST api. Try to use InvoiceRequest class as input and InvoiceDTO as output to separate view from business logic. That will also fix Jackson serialization/deserialization issues.