# Many to Many relationship is returning many nested results

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, associations

I have two tables [1]users and [2] employee_group 
I am trying to implement ManyToMany relationship and this is how I implemented using annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_group")
public class EmployeeGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employeeGroups")
    private List<User> users;
    .........
    // other properties 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "emp_group_map", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_emp_group") })
    private List<EmployeeGroup> employeeGroups;
    .........
    // other properties 
}
```

**Expectation:** I have one user (for example: userId 100) and two employee groups in which this user belongs, so I am expecting that when I try to get this user by userId saay 100 it will get user details with employee group list and this employeeGroups will be having two records.

**Issue:** This returns nested results like:

```
{
    "id": 11,       
    "employeeGroups": [
        {
            "id": 1,           
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 11,                   
                    "employeeGroups": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,                            
                            "users": [
                                {
                                    "id": 11,                                   
                                    "employeeGroups": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 1,                                            
                                            "users": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": 11,                                                   
                                                    "employeeGroups": [
                                                        {                                                            
                                                            "id": 1,                                                            
                                                            "users": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "id": 11,
```

I stuck here and not getting that exactly what is wrong. I am using Spring-Boot 2.6.4.

Comment: I think this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69250570/2143128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson will be going in to `User`, sees the `employeeGroup` so it goes in to that, which has a `List<User>` so it starts to go over those, again getting the user, then its employee group etc.
This leads to the potential OOM.

`@JsonManagedReference` `@JsonBackReference` may be of use to you.

Also, consider using a DTO as I am assuming you are trying to return a user out of a controller (so jackson will map it).

Using a DTO `Data Transfer Object`, you will de-couple the entity and the returned DTO from the controller and also more easily customise and handle what is returned and the structure of it.